# Compress the string in java

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

Please help with the java code below.
When I give input, for example, aabbcccd,
the output is 99100102d, but it should be a2b2c3d.
Can anyone tell what's my mistake in this code? (This code tries to capture input and output how often a specific char has been typed)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
            String s = scn.nextLine();                     // taking input
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(s);              
            StringBuilder str_new = new StringBuilder();

            int i = 0 ;
            while (i < str.length()) {
                int count = 1; 
                while (i < str.length()-1 && str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i+1)){
                    count += 1;
                    i++;
                }
                if (count == 1)
                    str_new.append(str.charAt(i));
                else
                    str_new.append(str.charAt(i) + (char)count);
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println(str_new);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, as you have now answers now, you may think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to reward the one that gives you the most helpful comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from `str.charAt(i) + (char)count`, as they are 2 chars, they are summed up with their `int` value,

---

Solve that by using consecutive `append()` calls

```
str_new.append(str.charAt(i)).append(count);
```

---

You can reduce the code by using an outer `for-loop` and a ternary operator in the `append`, and increment only `i` in the inner `while` by saving `i` before

```
int count;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    count = i;
    while (i < str.length() - 1 && str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i + 1)) {
        i++;
    }
    str_new.append(str.charAt(i)).append((i - count) == 0 ? "" : (i - count + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your primary issue was the used of the `StringBuilder` and entering the values which I show in this example.  But in this case I am using regular expressions.

- `(.)` is a capture block that matches on any character
- `\\1*` refers to the first capture block followed by 0 or more of the same character.

The following code constructs the Matcher for the entered text and then continues to find subsequent matches.  They could be printed out as found or placed in a `StringBuilder` as I chose to do.

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
String text = scn.nextLine();

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1*").matcher(text);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (m.find()) {
    String s = m.group();
    int count = s.length();
    sb.append(s.charAt(0)).append(count > 1 ? count : "");
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

for `aaabbbbcadb` Prints

```
a3b4cadb
```